# Problema con el jQuery ui y el select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, select2

En estos momentos estoy tratando de solucionar un problema que tengo y es que cuando se activa la funcion `datepicker` de `jQuery ui` y el `select2` solo me toma la primera casilla de la tabla, ¿me pueden ayudar como hago para que me le coloque los atributos de `select2` y `jQuery ui` a todo los resultados que me salgan? Les dejaré el código para que vean que tengo de malo.

Este es el código de Laravel con el que hago la consulta

```
@foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
    @if($pedido->granja_id == $g->granja_id)
        @if($pedido->fecha_entrega == 'por verificar' || $pedido->conductor_asignado == 'por verificar' || $pedido->vehiculo_asignado == 'por verificar')
            @if(Auth::User()->rol_id == 10)
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.show', $pedido->consecutivo) }}">
                            <strong>PCO{{ $pedido->consecutivo }}</strong>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td>{{ $pedido->nombre_granja }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_creacion }}</td>
                    <td> {{$pedido->fecha_estimada}} </td>
                    @if($pedido->estado_id == 1)
                        <td><strong style="color: #FDAE05;"> En Tramite </strong></td>
                    @elseif($pedido->estado_id == 2)
                        <td><strong style="color: #8BC34A;"> Tramitado </strong></td>
                    @endif
                    <td>
                        <strong>
                            <input id="modificar_fecha_pedido_concentrados" class="form-control" type="text" name="conductor" value="{{ $pedido->fecha_entrega }}" readonly="true" />
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="conductor" class="form-control" id="cd" selected="selected" />
                            @if($pedido->conductor_asignado == 'por verificar')
                                <option value="por verificar">{{ $pedido->conductor_asignado }}</option>
                                @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                    <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                    @if($pedido->conductor_asignado == $c->nombre)
                                        <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                    <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>  
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <select name="conductor" class="form-control" id="vh" selected="selected">
                            @if($pedido->vehiculo_asignado == 'por verificar')
                                <option value="por verificar">{{ $pedido->vehiculo_asignado }}</option>
                                @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                    <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                    @if($pedido->vehiculo_asignado == $v->placa)
                                        <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                    <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="validar" onclick="enviarCampos({{ $pedido->consecutivo }});"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Validar</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

Con este pequeño código de `javascript` hago la función de establecerles los atributos pero solo me toma la primera fila y le pone los atributos pero de ahí para abajo estan normales

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cd").select2();
    $("#vh").select2();
    $("#modificar_fecha_pedido_concentrados").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1950:2100",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showButtonPanel: true,
    });
});
```

Con este código le establezco los atributos de las librerias pero el problema es que solo me esta tomando la primera fila
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si notan que los dos `selects` son difrentes a los de abajo es por que tienen los atributos de la libreria `select2` y el primer `input` tiene el atributo de `jQuery ui` pero el segundo no los tiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en estas lineas:

```
$("#cd").select2();
$("#vh").select2();
$("#modificar_fecha_pedido_concentrados").datepicker({
```

Estas utilizando ids para identificar varios elementos.  Los ids se supone que deben de ser unicos en todo el DOM.  La solucion es usar clases en lugar de ids.

Comment: @alanfm ya solucione el de las fechas pero el otro problema es que cuando selecciono la segunda fila, al cambiarle la fecha me cambia la de arriba visualmente, pero en base de datos se cambia normalmente

Comment: Me parece que esa seria otra pregunta porque tendria que ver el codigo.  Mientras tanto, si esta respuesta te funciono, marcala como aceptada.